# Java issue, Can't print both methods

Tags: java, arraylist

```
     package messagelist;
     import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.List;
     import java.util.Scanner;
     import java.util.Random;



    public class Messagelist {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

           //create an ArrayList object

           List list = new ArrayList();

         //Add elements to Arraylist

         list.add(0, "I love Java Programming."); 
         list.add(1, "Java programming is so much fun."); 
         list.add(2, "Who needs C ++, when you have Java."); 
         list.add(3, "Java can be hard.");
         list.add(4, "I would be happy when I get an A."); 
         list.add(5, "I love Jave the coffee also."); 
         list.add(6, "Who wants to Learn Java."); 
         list.add(7, "I'm taking a vacation after this class.");
         list.add(8, "Only two more questions to go."); 
         list.add(9, "What course should I take next?");

       System.out.println("Retrieving stored messages from Arraylist");
       shoutOutCannedMessage(list);

         }


          //This method retrieves values from ArrayList using get method


        public static void shoutOutCannedMessage(List list)
        {


              //Retrieving values from list

        int size = list.size();
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)

        {

            System.out.println(list.get(i));
            System.out.println("**********************\n\n");
        }


          int userIndex;
          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Please enter the index number you wish to search");
          userIndex = scanner.nextInt();
          System.out.println(list.get(userIndex));
        }
```

The above method prints as expected but the below code does not. For this project I'm required to have a `shoutOutCannedMethod` and a `shoutOutRandomMethod`, but only the canned method works.

```
        public static void ShoutOutRandomMessage() {

        int i;

      //holds the words to be generated.

      String[] subject= {" He's", " I'm", " She"};
      String[] verb= {" eating", " catching", " studying", " caughing"};
      String[] adjective= {" funny", " hard", " good", " polite"};
      String[] object= {" course", " homework", " books", " dog"};
      String[] adverb= {" quickly. ", " everywhere. ", " accordingly. ", " awfully. "};


       Random r = new Random(); //intialize a Random
       int selectedElement = r.nextInt(subject.length);

      //randomly create sentence.

      for (i=1; i<=1; i++)

     {

     String randomSentence=subject[selectedElement] 
      + verb[selectedElement]       
      + adjective[selectedElement] 
      + object[selectedElement]
      + adverb[selectedElement];

     System.out.println("ShoutOut: " + randomSentence );

      }
      }
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're calling ShoutOutRandomMessage().  At least, not from the code you've posted.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: What is the purpose of `for (i=1; i<=1; i++)`?

Comment: The second method should generate a random message from the arraylist.

Comment: I can run both methods seperately and they will produce the desired results but together they do not. I guess I do not need the for (i=1; i<=1; i++).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't call your method shoutOutRandomMessage so it is never executed.

Add

```
ShoutOutRandomMessage();
```

In your main method below

```
shoutOutCannedMessage(list);
```

and it will print out the random message after you enter the index you want for the first method.

Doing this I got this  result:

```
Please enter the index number you wish to search
3
Java can be hard.
ShoutOut:  I'm catching hard homework everywhere.
```

Comment: Thanks John, that worked but I'm getting a compile error when it runs but if I hit continue and it prints out both messages.

Comment: I've copied your code and don't have any errors. Can you copy the line for me?

Comment: shoutOutCannedMessage(list);
ShoutOutRandomMessage();   it may be something else going on if you were able to run without errors. I'm going to create a new project and add the code to start fresh. Thanks again John, you are a major help.

Comment: does your compiler give you an error? For example if you are using eclipse you can hover over the text with the cursor and it will display the error.

Comment: It's just a generic popup box that does not give an error, I can choose to always run without asking but I didn't want it to be a problem.

Comment: Those lines of code are fine. Check around it that you have closed all brackets etc.

Comment: I created a new project and added code, did not have a problem in new project. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Your random number is only generated once.  The same number is used for the verb, adjective, etc.  So if the random generator returns 0, you'll get "He's eating funny course quickly."  I'm guessing your for loop was going to generate a random number for each array, but you got sidetracked.  What is the output you're getting (you only say it's not printing out as expected)?

Comment: Trasd- the main method returns the first arraylist, and the second method should print out what you are saying. The random number should only generate once for the second arraylist not the first. When I run the program together only the first method prints and not the second. I need both to print.

Comment: And what happens if the random number is a 3 (the fourth element in the array) because subject only has 3 elements and the others have 4?  I think you need to start over with this project.  How are you even running them (separately, or is there code you are not showing that runs them both)?

Comment: It can never be 3 because you are making it a random number based on the length of "subject" which only has 3 elements.

Comment: True John, but my point is that the logic is all over the place, not that the 4th elements will never be reached.

Comment: I added a fourth element to be in line with the others.

Comment: I still think you should start over and rethink your logic Scott, but maybe I'm just not understanding - it's been a long day!

Comment: Thanks Trasd, yes it has been a long day. but according to documents that were posted it does what is expected.